# Prevent Firebug from Removing HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm sure we've all done it by now. A website pops up some goofy JavaScript modal preventing you from continuing. You whip out Firebug, inspect it, and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Poof! Gone. Now, is there a way with JavaScript to recreate the element or disable that functionality altogether? Thanks!

Comment: You could add events to the elements to create a duplicate element before it gets destroyed. Haven't tried this out, but in theory it should work.

Comment: I don't know that I want to help you... I like being able to remove the popup and going on my merry way...

Answer (score 1):

Create a js reference to the element on page load. Add a listener to the element that looks for the destroy event. If that happens, then use your reference to recreate the item. The only issue is firebug might not fire a destroy event when an element is manually deleted. In that case, you could have a loop that checks every x milliseconds to see if the element is there. If it isn't, then create a new one.

Comment: That's a really great breakdown. I'll give it a shot and see if it suffices—I'm sure it will. Thanks.